# Solve for steady state

Tags: systems-of-equations, economics, steady-state

I am trying to solve for the steady state (in the context of a [DSGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_stochastic_general_equilibrium) economic model) and one of the equations is reffering to capital accumulation. Particularly:

$$K_t=(1 - \Delta)K_{t-1} + \left( 1 - \frac{k_i}2 \left( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} - 1 \right)^2 \right)I_t$$

With

- $K_t ={}$ capital
- $d = {}$ depreciation
- $k_i = {}$ adjustments costs
- $I_t = {}$ Investment

I am substituting $I_t = \Delta K_t$ (a general calibration advise) and try to solve in respect for $K$'s steady state. I am concluding $K=K$ which means that there is an infinite number of solutions. Is this statement correct? For example can I use $K=1$ and try to solve the rest system of equation for the steady state. Is this approach correct?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin i have edit the post. Is that ok now? Any help on my request

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this incorrectly. In the steady state all variable should be constant. So you should impose that $K_t=K_{t+1}=K$ and $I_t=I_{t+1}=I$. If you plug this into your equation, you obtain $K=\delta I$. So the conclusion is that in the steady state, the investment just covers the depreciation of existing capital. But you still need to solve for $K$.

To solve for $K$ you have to consider the whole system of equilibrium conditions. This will typically be a non-linear system which will have to be solved numerically.

Comment: Thank you @Mdoc for the answer. The thing is that i am trying to solve a system of 30 equations (with 30 unknowns) and i am a bit confused. For example one of the equations is 1/c_t={E_t}(betta_p(1+r^ib)/c_{t+1}) where {E_t} is the expectation operator. When solving for the ss since c_t=c_{t+1}=1 I get 1= betta_p(1+r^ib). However, this solution doesn't seem to stand with the rest of the paper(system) as the author has calibrated betta_p and r_ib with numerical values to solve for the rest of the system and didn't use the solutions from the above equation. I am missing something in the logic?

Comment: You don't solve those models analytically, but numerically. Typically using dynare. The manual to dynare should have plenty of example how to solve models like this.